# Retrieve items from a database in the form of a doubly linked list via JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Suppose I have a playlist of songs. Song is a class and Playlist is a class and both are being stored as tables. The one to many relationship between Playlist and Song is stored in a separate table, and the order is maintained as a doubly-linked list

e.g.

```
Playlist
 id
 name

Song
 id
 name

PlayListSong
 playlistId
 songId
 prevSongId
 nextSongId
 isHead (I think this is needed to know where to start)
```

Building this via Spring-Boot and using Postgres and JPA Repository, what's the best way to retrieve all the songs, sort them and return them in a GET request? I was thinking to build it myself by grabbing the head and then creating the linked list from scratch, but if there's a better way please let me know (i.e. built-in JPA methods, Collection methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know of any JPA methods for solving this.
The best way to retrieve and sort with a SQL data source would be not having a linked list I guess. Why do you need the linked list, what requirement do you need to fulfil?

I would consider looking into a graph database if you really really need this form of data representation.

Besides that, I think:

- PlayListSong should not hold references to `prev/nextSongId`, but to `prev/nextPlayListSongId`.
- isHead can be omitted, because it is equivalent to `prevSongID` not being existent.
- Instead of fetching all entries and then sorting, I would suggest to traverse the tree.

Comment: That's an excellent point about prev/next being the pk of the PlayListSong table. I basically wanted to solve for rearranging the order of a song in O(1) time complexity as opposed to getting the entire playlist, inserting an ID and shifting the elements down

Comment: That might be a matter of pragmatism. How long are your playlists in average or median? :) With the usual optimisations in place (indexes), it should still be sufficiently fast I think.

Comment: Ya that's true, if the playlist is like only 100 songs then updating it shouldn't be that big of a hassle :)

Comment: Even thousands of it. Without looking at optimizations, I quickly ran a test project, running locally on Docker with 1GB of RAM and 1 CPU core. Under the hood it very dumb deleted all of the playlist songs and then saved it again (song by song) with the new order. Size 100000: 3s. Size 10000: 500ms. Size 1000: 300ms.